# ajax inject html into a div but keep the html elements including their ids

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am using some ajax to call a php file that returns some html (an image and couple of buttons) and then place the contents of this into a div. The trouble is that I want to be able to use the id of one of the buttons that is returned from the php to hook up an event handler. The output of the source if I do view source in browser simply shows the div that the html is injected into and not the html:

```
<div class="displaysomething"></div>
```

My AJAX is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   getServiceDisplay();
   $('#stop-service').click(function(e)
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       runHDIMService();
   });
```

}

```
function getServiceDisplay(){
$.ajax(
{ 
    url: 'includes/dosomething.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(strOutput) 
    {
        $(".displaysomething").html(strOutput);
        }               
    }); 
};
```

PHP  - Ultimately returns a button amongst other stuff. This is what I need to hook up to the event handler, based on its id.

```
echo '<input id="stop-service" type="button" value="Run" class="'.$strRunActionButtonClass.'"/>';
```

If I simply put a button on the page without injecting it using AJAX into the div my button hookup code works great.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, the `.click(...` method of adding an event handler will only add the event to existing elements. New elements added later are no included.

You can use the [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method of event binding to include elements added later.

```
$("body").on("click", "#stop-service", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    runHDIMService();
});
```

I have created a [simple example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jr79n/).

Comment: That works great! I was thinking along those lines but was going to put a wait/sleep in which probably wouldn't have worked and is very crude. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
   getServiceDisplay();
   $('#stop-service').click(function(e) // this doesn't exists yet
   {
       e.preventDefault();
       runHDIMService();
   });
```

This should work:

function getServiceDisplay(){

```
$.ajax(
{ 
    url: 'includes/dosomething.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(strOutput) 
    {
        $(".displaysomething").html(strOutput);
        // so after you attached the div from ajax call just register your event
        $('#stop-service').click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            runHDIMService();
        });               
    }); 
};
```